# Python triggering / simulating Custom Browser Protocol

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I want to make a python script that will automatically join zoom meeting at a specified time

when using browser you could use this url zoommtg://us02.zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=1234567890&pwd=Z1hTRjUwampocmR1VEh4aWkrSkZUdz09 to automatically join,

how do I trigger this Custom Browser Protocol directly in a python script without using a browser?

since a browser normally prompt you to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) wants to open this application

Comment: The special protocol simply calls a command line application via a shortcut. You should look up how the protocol is defined in the registry to directly open the program.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1563255/start-a-zoom-meeting-from-the-command-line